# Partition the data frame using column X and writes the data without column X

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, cloudera, hortonworks-data-platform, aws-glue-spark

How can I write the partition by column X and writes the data without Column X values?

I had a data frame with two-columns and the values are as shown below.

pkey string, output_value string

Values as

```
pkey ===== output_value

100  ===== 100-Hundred-some-text-value

100  ===== 101-Hundred-some-text-value

200  ===== 200-TwoHundred-some-text-value

300  ===== 300-ThreeHundred-some-text-value
```

How can I write this data frame using partition by pkey value and write only output_value?

output:

```
......./target-dir/stage-100/somefilename_100.csv

......./target-dir/stage-200/somefilename_200.csv

......./target-dir/stage-300/somefilename_300.csv
```

somefilename_100.csv should have the below entries:

```
100-Hundred-some-text-value

101-Hundred-some-text-value
```

somefilename_200.csv should have the below entries:

```
200-TwoHundred-some-text-value
```

somefilename_300.csv should have the below entries:

```
300-ThreeHundred-some-text-value
```

I tried like the below code, but the compiler is expecting the data frame should have both columns.

```
df.select('output_value')
   .write()
   .partitionBy('pkey')
```

Answer (score 0):

By only selecting `output_value` you are striping your Dataframe of `pkey` column at that moment

partitionBy would output your Data by `pkey` column instead , keeping it out from your final output within the file

Removing the `select` clause would be enough to accomplish this

```
df.write.partitionBy("pkey") \
        .mode("overwrite") \
        .csv("<path>")
```

However the file names within each partition would start with `part-*`